# Convert varchar 'hh:mm:ss' to datetime hh:mm:ss in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I tried to convert a `varchar` variable stored in my database as `HH:MM:SS` to an actual `datetime` format HH:MM:SS. I did get the value for HH:MM:SS but the attempt also prefixed the YYYY:MM:DD along with the expected result.

Following is the code that I used to convert this `varchar` value to HH:MM:SS and the result I got.

Code I tried :

```
DECLARE @Duration Varchar(10)
SET @Duration = '00:01:23'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, Duration, 8) AS duration
```

The output I got :

```
1900-01-01 00:01:23.000
```

The expected output:

```
00:01:23
```

Please let me know what needs to be changed in this. Thank you!

Comment: The expectation is wrong. That's not a datetime, it's only a time. A duration isn't a date. Those aren't prefixes either - `datetime`, `date`, `time` etc are *binary* types, not strings

Comment: Seems you want the time data type not the datetime data type

Answer (score 4):

If you want `time`, why are you converting to `datetime`? Given the name it shouldn't be surprising you get both date and time. Try:

```
DECLARE @Duration char(8) = '00:01:23';
SELECT duration = CONVERT(time(0), @Duration);
```

Results:

| duration |
| --- |
| 00:01:23 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f072395ae26e2ffcc749ffb1398c7851)

Just keep in mind that `time` (nor any date/time type) is *not* meant to represent a duration or interval. Because what happens when your duration or interval exceeds 24 hours?

Comment: It's a bit ... unusual that SQL Server doesn't have a proper interval type yet

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, but to be fair, adding types is hard. The types added in 2008 haven't exactly had a perfect track record and they haven't tried since.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt help all of you. I was a bit confused with this, but your code helped me. thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

What you posted is a time, not a date or datetime. A duration isn't a date. The date types are binary, they don't have prefixes.

You can define a time directly with :

```
Declare @Duration time ='00:01:23'
```

Or you can cast a string to a time:

```
Declare @Duration varchar(10)
Set @Duration = '00:01:23'
Select cast(@Duration as time)  as duration
```

or

```
Declare @Duration varchar(10)
Set @Duration = '00:01:23'
Select convert(time, @Duration,8)  as duration
```

**Unfortunately** that's not a duration, it's a time of day. It can only store values between `00:00` and `23:59:59.9999999`.

SQL Server has no interval/duration type.

---

Comment: Thank you for your help! these comments helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @Duration Varchar(10) 
Set @Duration = '00:01:23'
select convert(time,@duration,8);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :)